# Find the value of $a, b$ and $c$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> let $A$ be   a $3 \times 3$ matrix  with complex entries  whose  eigenvalue  are $1,i$ and $-2i$. If $A^{-1} = aA^2 +bA + cI$, where $I$ is  the idenity matrix   , with $a, b$ ,$c \in \mathbb{C}$. Find the  value of $a, b$ and $c$.

My attempt : I got  3 equation from  the given condition of question

$a+b+c= 1$

$-a+bi +c=-i$

$-4a-2ib+c= \frac{i}{2}$

Now  i don't  know  how  to find the value of $a$, $b$ and $c$?

Comment: The elegant way to describe $A$ would be as a square matrix of order $3$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eigen values are roots of minimal polynomial. Minimal polynomial of matrix $A$ is

$$\frac{1}{a}(aA^3+bA^2+cA-I)=0$$

Therefore write $$ax^3+bx^2+cx-1=a(x-1)(x-i)(x+2i)$$
Now, solve for $a, b$ and $c$.

Comment: Why u write $1/a $ in the beginning of equation ?

Comment: @jasmine, because minimal polynomial is monic.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

- Multiply $A^{-1} = aA^2 +bA + cI$ by $A$.
- Bring all to one side and use Cayley-Hamilton on $a(A^3 + \frac{b}{a}A^2+\frac ca A - \frac 1aI) = 0_{3\times 3}$